# Dispose of a non disposed CTabFolder raises SWTException: Widget is disposed

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my Eclipse 4 RCP App I want to dispose some [CTabFolders](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCTabFolder.html). I check if they are already disposed and if not I dispose them. But it still raises an [SWTException](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2FSWTException.html): Widget is disposed. 
I checked if every [CTabFolder](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCTabFolder.html) in stageDataTabFolders is unique.

Here is the code fragment:

```
for (Tuple<CTabItem, CTabFolder> stageDataTabFolder : stageDataTabFolders) {
  if (!stageDataTabFolder.getSecond().isDisposed()) {
    stageDataTabFolder.getSecond().dispose();
  }
}
```

And the Exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2016-04-11 11:28:20.317
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/LifeCycle/activate] to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@da28d03
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Widget.java:562)
at     org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.isStylable(AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.java:118)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.getElement(AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.java:97)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.dom.ArrayNodeList.item(ArrayNodeList.java:38)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:354)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:354)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.engine.AbstractCSSEngine.applyStyles(AbstractCSSEngine.java:354)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.applyStyles(ThemeEngine.java:512)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$11.setClassnameAndId(PartRenderingEngine.java:1321)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.setCSSInfo(SWTPartRenderer.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.styleElement(SWTPartRenderer.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$5.handleEvent(StackRenderer.java:520)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.UIEvents.publishEvent(UIEvents.java:372)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.UIEvents.publishEvent(UIEvents.java:341)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:657)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:620)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:61)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1416)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.sendFocusEvent(Control.java:2855)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmSetFocus(Widget.java:2425)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_SETFOCUS(Control.java:5236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4680)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DestroyWindow(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.destroyWidget(Control.java:779)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:826)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:454)
at de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.parts.stage.StagePart.dispose(StagePart.java:416)
at de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.menu.New.resetEditor(New.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:164)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Edit: I created them like this:

```
CTabFolder stageTabFolder = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FLAT);
stageTabFolder.setSimple(false);
stageTabFolder.setTabPosition(SWT.BOTTOM);

CTabFolder stageDataTabFolder = new CTabFolder(stageTabFolder, SWT.TOP);
stageDataTabFolder.setSimple(false);
stageDataTabFolders.add(new Tuple<CTabItem, CTabFolder>(stageTabItem,
            stageDataTabFolder));
```

Edit: The whole purpose is to implement a menu Item "New" to reset the App back into a virgin state. The call goes like this:

```
@Execute
  public void resetEditor(MApplication app, IWorkbench workbench) {
    MPart configPart = partService
            .findPart("de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.parts.config");
    MPart stagePart = partService
            .findPart("de.uni_due.s3.jack.editor.part.stage");
    resetHandler();
    ((StagePart)stagePart.getObject()).dispose();
    partService.activate(configPart);
}
```

On the StagePart:

```
public void dispose() {
  for (Tuple<CTabItem, CTabFolder> stageDataTabFolder : stageDataTabFolders) {
    if (!stageDataTabFolder.getSecond().isDisposed()) {
            stageDataTabFolder.getSecond().dispose();
    }
  }
  stageDataTabFolders.clear();
  stageTabFolder.dispose();
}
```

Comment: What are these CTabFolders? It looks as though they may be application model objects which you should not dispose yourself. Show us how you created them.

Comment: Added the creation of the CTabFolders in the code.

Comment: What is your `New.resetEditor` method doing? It looks like you may be trying to dispose of a model object directly - which is not allowed.

Comment: The purpose of this all is to reset the Editor I´m developing back into a "vigrin" state when someone hits the menu Item "New". The demand is to not restart the whole app (at first I used workbench.restart();)
The resetEditor Method calls dispose in my Stages to dispose View Elements I saved (I have stageDataTabFolders in a List). I´ll add some code in the main question in a moment

Comment: Well your dispose is causing the Eclipse code to try and activate something with disposed controls. Since I don't run Windows I can't reproduce this exact sequence. It may be better to use `EPartService.hidePart` and `showPart` rather than the dispose and activate calls.